# How to switch from Gameover screen to Menu screen in Libgdx?

Tags: android, menu, libgdx, screen, box2d

I am implementing a 2d platformer game. When the player falls down it displays a game over screen. But on clicking the screen it should direct to Menu screen but it's not happening. Instead, the Game over text in the screen expands.
Here is my Game over screen code. In handleInput, I have written the code for changing the state of game over screen to the menu screen

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you don't share too much code. You should remove irrelevant code when you post a question.And most of it is irrelevant. You should share how GameState class works, how you navigate.

Are you trying to navigate with this code?

```
 if (MyInput.isPressed()) {
            if (MyInput.x < Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) {

                gsm.getState(GameStateManager.MENU, level);
            }
           else

               gsm.getState(GameStateManager.MENU, level);
            }
        }
```

If so, it might be cause you are trying to **get** state instead of setting it.

Why don't you extend `ScreenAdapter` and use `setScreen(new MenuScreen())` to change screens. You probably watched first tutorials and learned extending custom classes like MenuState, like i did when i first started learning LibGDX, then i saw most of the tutorials and code shared uses Game and ScreenAdapter classes or Screen interface to navigate between screens.

Basic set up for multi screen games for game

set ENUM or int states like STATE=RUNNING, PAUSED, LEVEL_UP, GAME_OVER

and setScreen() depending on the state of your game screen.

```
public MyGame extends Game {

  public void create() {
      setScreen(new GameScreen(this));
  }

}

public GameScreen extends ScreenAdapter {
    // You define a state to watch different states of your game
    private int state = RUNNING;
    private MyGame game;
  public GameScreen(MyGame myGame) {
    game = myGame;
  }


   void handleInput() {
      if(state==FINISHED) {
       game.setScreen(new MenuScreen(game));
      }
   }
}
```

This is the basic structure for your game and screens. Check out `Game` class and `Screen` interface of `LibGDX` to see how they work.

Comment: how to use the setScreen method to change screens?If I want to change the state of GamestateManager how would I be able to change to Menu Screen?I have a class for Menu,Game over screen and Play screen.If I now extend ScrenAdapter I have to delete MenuState,Play,GameOver class.I dont want to do that.

Comment: You can check out LibGDX tutorials to see how it's used. And i explained it basically. You use a field to watch state of your game screen and use setScreen() of Game class. Your main class should extend Game and your screens should extend ScreenAdapter class to able to set by Game class. GameScreen gameScreen = new GameScreen(game);

game.setScreen(new MenuScreen(game)); for example